# jquery what is the proper json object to parse

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

please help me fix this json object.I am stuck here and cannot figure it out.

I am getting a json object(but I am not sure if it is correct). I am trying 4 ways to display the result of json but nothing works. Please help me find what I am doing wrong

here is json object created in webmethod c#

```
return_str += "{'id':'" + p_id + "','firstname':'" + firstname + "','lastname':'" + lastname + "','prefix':'" + prefix + "','gender':'" + gender + "','mobilephone':'" + mobilephone + "','email':'" + email + "','diplomano':'" + diplomano + "'}";
```

here is the jquery code that tries to get the json and display the results

```
 $('#btn_second').click(function () {
            //$('#txt_isim_4').val('test arif');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Registration.aspx/get_selected_professional",
                data: "{'id':'2'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('1:' + data);  // shows "[object Object]"
                    alert('2:' + data.id);  // shows "undefined"
                    alert('3:' + data.d);  // shows json string
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data); 
                    alert('4:' + json.id);  // doesnt show the alert box, I think It throws and error
                }
            });
```

How can I display the firstname ?
            });

Comment: validate your json here.http://jsonlint.com

Comment: What does the actual JSON look like?

Comment: why you are parsing manually ? have u heard  JSON seralizer ? use JSON.Net

Comment: Have you tried `data.d.id`? http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Comment: If you use developer tools, like say in IE, hit F12, then look at your Network Traffic, you can look at the response details to see how your JSON response is formatted on its way back from the server.  That might help you figure out your formatting on the C# side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using web service so you will have to go for `data.d`

```
$('#btn_second').click(function () {
        //$('#txt_isim_4').val('test arif');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Registration.aspx/get_selected_professional",
            data: "{'id':'2'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d.id);

            }
        });
```

the proper way is this

```
  $('#btn_second').click(function () {
        //$('#txt_isim_4').val('test arif');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Registration.aspx/get_selected_professional",
            data: "{'id':'2'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               data=$.parseJSON(data.d);
                alert(data.id);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

`'` are not valid in JSON, use `"` instead+#

This should work:

```
return_str += "{\"id\":\"" + p_id + "\",\"firstname\":\"" + firstname + "\",\"lastname\":\"" + lastname + "\",\"prefix\":\"" + prefix + "\",\"gender\":\"" + gender + "\",\"mobilephone\":\"" + mobilephone + "\",\"email\":\"" + email + "\",\"diplomano\":\"" + diplomano + "\"}";
```

From json.org:

> A value can be a string in **double quotes**, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

Comment: should use square brackets?

Comment: I did the way u told me. now how can I display the data, should I use data.firstname?

Comment: I found my problem but I dont know how to solve it. I used firebug to see json object and it returns {"d":"{\"id\":\"2\",\"firstname\":\"Arif2\",\"lastname\":\"Yilmaz2\",\"prefix\":\"1\",\"gender\":\"1\",\"mobilephone\":\"05325657588    \",\"email\":\"2ayilmaz@eniyihekim.com\",\"diplomano\":\"34560\"}"}     which means it puts the returned json object in data.d as a string

Comment: it's because in C# you use double quotes to escape double quotes, not backslash.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma

Comment: I had to use  this solution to solve - var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);